# How can I make the radio buttons update

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Does anyone know how I can make it so the total value is live updated depending on which radio button is selected and the value of the range selector? All I get is `Total Value: 50[object HTMLInputElement]`.

```js
var drink = document.querySelector('[name="drink"]:checked');
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    
    output.innerHTML = Number(slider.value) + drink;
    slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = Number(slider.value) + drink;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
   <input type="radio" class="r1" name="drink" value="50"> Cider/ Beer<br>
    <input type="radio" class="r1" checked="checked" name="drink" value="20"> Wine<br>
    <input type="radio" class="r1" name="drink" value="30"> Spirits
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

    <p>Total Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to include the name of the product in the Total Value?  For example can the total value simply be: `Total Value: 50`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your input value as the name on the radio.

```js
 var drink = document.querySelector('[name="drink"]:checked').value;
 var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
 var output = document.getElementById("demo");
 output.innerHTML = Number(slider.value) +' '+ drink;

 slider.oninput = function() {
    changeName()
 }

 function changeName(){
   drink = document.querySelector('[name="drink"]:checked').value;
   output.innerHTML = Number(slider.value) + ' ' +drink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="radio" class="r1" name="drink" value="Cider/ Beer" onchange="changeName()"> Cider/ Beer<br>
  <input type="radio" class="r1" checked="checked" name="drink" value="Wine" onchange="changeName()"> Wine<br>
  <input type="radio" class="r1" name="drink" value="Spirits" onchange="changeName()"> Spirits
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">

  <p>Total Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```